# how to draw a horizontal and vertical line under specific gridcolumn in wpf

Tags: wpf, grid

[image]I'm trying to draw a vertical line under a specific column.so anyone tell me how to draw a line horizontally and vertically

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDataGrid.GroupBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="GroupBox" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="186"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="72"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Header="Select Option" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="gb1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="11" Padding="11">
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Content="Add Cream" Margin="3.5"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Add Suger" Margin="3.5"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Add Flavering" Margin="3.5"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Add Biscuit" Margin="3.5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <Separator Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't see any columns in your code...

Comment: i know but i want this

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<Separator/>` [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.separator(v=vs.110).aspx)

or maybe a `GridSplitter` [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter(v=vs.110).aspx)

here is a sample of both:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="259"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="Some text"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox  Text="Some text"/>
        <Separator />
        <TextBox Text="2nd text box"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="Some Text" Grid.Column="1" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="3" Background="Black"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="Auto" Height="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: again check my question then give me solution.

Comment: try my sample and you will see how to define grid columns.  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="259"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Answer (score 1):

It's Pretty Easy. Pick your Grid location and Y1, Y2 for a vertical line or X1, X2 for a Horizontal Line. Below is an example for a vertical line.

`<Line Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Stroke="AliceBlue" StrokeThickness="4" Y1="100" Y2="600" Margin="20,0,0,0"></Line>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="lineStyle" TargetType="Line">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Gray" />
                    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="horizontalLineStyle" TargetType="Line" BasedOn="{StaticResource lineStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="X2" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="X1" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan"
                            Value="{Binding   
                            Path=ColumnDefinitions.Count,  
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" />
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="verticalLineStyle" TargetType="Line" BasedOn="{StaticResource lineStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="Y2" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan"
                            Value="{Binding   
                            Path=RowDefinitions.Count,  
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" />
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Line Style="{StaticResource horizontalLineStyle}" />
            <Line Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource horizontalLineStyle}" />
            <Line Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource horizontalLineStyle}" />

            <Line Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource verticalLineStyle}" />
            <Line Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource verticalLineStyle}" />
            <Line Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource verticalLineStyle}" />
            <Line Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource verticalLineStyle}" />
            <Line Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource verticalLineStyle}" />

            <Label Content="" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
            <Label Content="Dword" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
            <Label Content="Words" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
            <Label Content="Bytes" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
            <Label Content="Bits" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
</Grid>
```